# Fast Binding to Active Directory

Tags: c#, .net, ldap

Passthrough authentication in my web server application written in C# is performing extremely poorly; successful login events take as long as 10 or 15 seconds using the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagmeent` API.

I would like to switch to using `System.DirectoryServices.Protocols` and fast binding as described in this MSDN article [Using Fast Bind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc223503.aspx), but it is bereft of any details or code samples.

Can you point me to or provide examples of .NET code doing fast bind user authentication with `s.ds.p`?  I have been very unsuccessful googling.

Answer (score 0):

After more browsing, I found [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332056.aspx#sdspintro_topic6_perform) which does have complete C# code sample.

Answer (score 0):

Joe Kaplan's book [.NET Developer's Guide to Directory Services Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321350170) has some examples as well, that can be found [here](http://flylib.com/books/en/1.434.1.110/1/).